# Scaling a touch/mouse vector with a render texture?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So my game is designed for 1920x1080, i'm creating a render texture from my main camera and then stretching/shrinking that texture to the screen size of the device regardless of aspect... this produces some squashing on 4:3 etc but to be honest I prefer a little distortion to letterboxing and the game isn't suited to extending the background elements. (there are a few reasons for this)

Anyway, my game is reading input from the render camera (the one displaying the render texture) using "ScreenToWorld" but because the final render texture is squashed the touch positions don't match.

EG: Here is the 16:9 aspect, perfectly matches touch position

[image: 16:9 Version]

Here is the 4:3 version without texture being squashed (the edges of the screen are cropped off)... perfect again

[image: 4:3 No Stretch]

Here is the 4:3 version after its squashed, touch is being read from the camera that knows its 4:3 but doesn't realise the render textures is squashed, so its offset the further left or right I touch.

[image]

As far as I can tell in the case of the aspect examples above I need to scale up the touch position from the squashed texture to match the actual game but all of my attempts to get this right result in touch positions that aren't correct across multiple resolutions.

Anyone know the best way to approach this? or does unity have something built in I'm missing? Ive done this before with Matrices in XNA/Monogame but similar code in Unity doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing the problem out seems to have helped me solve it:

```
        Vector2 tempFingerPos = renderCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
        float actualAspect = (float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height; // Actual size
        float intendedAspect = 1920f / 1080f; //Original Size
        float finalAspect = intendedAspect / actualAspect;
        Debug.Log("FINAL ASPECT: " + finalAspect);

        tempFingerPos.x *= finalAspect; // Only multiply X because image is only squashed on X and unity Y is accurate
```

Turns out my previous experiments failed because I didn't cast to float or add 'f' forcing a floating point and it was giving me integer values... and using Matrices was just overkill.